# What is the meaning of power laws in physics?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, scale-invariance

I know the basic meaning of a power law. Scale invariance. Also that with negative exponents, bigger events occur more rarely, like in say earthquakes. But I can't seem to find more physical discussion on the consequences of finding these scaling laws. What kind of conclusions can one make as to the physical mechanism behind them?

Say, in a particular problem, I find that a particular quantity depends on the exact value of two variables. But it has a power-law relationship with only one of the variables, when varying each variable independently. What does this mean? And does a power-law with a positive exponent smaller than 1 mean anything special?

Comment: "a particular quantity depends on the exact value of two variables. But it has a power-law relationship with only one" Do you mean something of the form $z=x^af(y)$?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power laws can have several causes. In fact, these can mix because **power laws beget power laws**; for example,$$X_i\propto\prod_jA_j^{x_{ij}},\,Y\propto\prod_iX_i^{x_i}\prod_jA_j^{a_j}\implies Y\propto\prod_jA_j^{a_j+\sum_ix_ix_{ij}}.$$(For example, this explains $P=I^2R$.) So I can't so much give a complete account of where all power laws come from as illustrate to you how unfeasible that is, with a few examples of the "atomic" causes we can mix:

- Suppose we Taylor-expand $y$ as a function of $x$, and we expect $y(0)=0$ (or if we expect $y(c)=d$, shift $x,\,y$ so $c=d=0$). If there's no reason to expect $y^\prime(0)$ to also be $0$, we have a small-$x$ approximation $y\propto x$. For example, if $x$ is a small distance from equilibrium, we get Hooke's law, with the force (which is restoring if the equilibrium is stable) being proportional to $x$.
- If we *do* expect $y^\prime(0)=0=0$, we get a higher exponent. For example, the potential energy in Hooke's law scales as $x^2$, because the equilibrium has zero force, i.e. the potential's first derivative is $0$. (Of course, if the next derivative vanished too, the can would be kicked even further down the road.) Another general lesson here is that power laws can also beget power laws by calculus.
- Even higher-order corrections to first-order power laws may be power laws in their own right, if we take Taylor series seriously. For example, if a potential isn't really quadratic in disturbance from the equilibrium, how wrong is that approximation? The leading-order answer needs to be of even power at a global minimum, giving at least a [quartic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction). Indeed, if a potential *is* quartic, we may as well shift to delete the cubic term rather than the linear one (which explains why the lowest-order *anharmonic* term isn't cubic), and if we expect a $\Bbb Z_2$ symmetry the linear term is deleted anyway.
- If $y$ diverges as $x\to0$ (with a $1$- or $2$-sided limit), use $1/y$ in the above logic. You might get a power law of negative exponent, possibly mandated by Gauss's law on a surface (e.g. $g=\frac{GM}{R^2}$), or something analogous on a loop (e.g. $B=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}$). More generally, geometric effects may give exponents that are powers of the dimension of (literal or a vector) space.
- Dimensional analysis may mandate fractional powers, as may combining power laws in a more complicated way than described above. Example 1: the time to cook a volume-$V$ meal in an oven should go as $V^{2/3}/\alpha$, with $\alpha$ the heat equation's thermal diffusivity. Example 2: *ceteris paribus*, a planet of orbital radius $R$ (let's neglect eccentricity) gets $R^{-2}$ light intensity, so $P=\sigma AT^4$ suggests the surface temperature goes as $R^{-1/2}$.
- Finally, some power laws are just linearized approximations of complicated $\ln y$-$\ln x$ relationships. In stellar physics, these are convenient because characteristics of a star vary over many orders of magnitude. We often divide these values by those obtained with the Sun to non-dimensionalize everything, then work in logarithms for comparisons. Logarithms vary little enough for us to attempt a linear regression. Unfortunately, the exponents may well be [large](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39051/how-can-such-a-high-exponent-arise-in-this-physics-equation), approximate and theoretically unmotivated.

There are also probably other causes I didn't think of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The last case is of particular interest to me. Is there any particular meaning to get out of such power-laws when we can get them? For example, if a quantity has a power-law relationship when varying one variable, but not for the other variable. Does it say something about the physics behind this?

Comment: @BitterDecoction Consider Planck's law,$$B(\nu,\,T)=\frac{2k_{B}^{3}}{\left(ch\right)^{2}}T^{3}\frac{x^{3}}{e^{x}-1},\,x:=\frac{h\nu}{k_BT}.$$You're asking why it's a power law in $T$, but not in $x$; but you're also asking countless other questions like that. If power laws can have many meanings, imagine how many meanings arbitrary alternatives can have!

Comment: @BitterDecoction As for the last case, it's fertile ground for arbitrary alternatives. All it means is we find power laws useful in that range. If we expand $\ln y$ as a Taylor series in $\ln x$, the next level of precision is to include a $\ln^2x$ term, which makes $y$ a power of $x$ times a power of $x^{\ln x}$, already quite complicated.

Comment: (I also forgot a multiplicative constant.)