# Higher powers in physics formulae

Tags: notation, big-list

A huge number of formulae involve second powers (squares).  For example, the very famous:

$$e = m c^2$$

Third powers (cubes) are also common e.g. volumes:

$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$$

Fourth powers occur occasionally.  E.g. Stefan-Boltzmann:

$$P = \sigma T^4$$

For a long time, that was the only example of a fourth power that I knew.  I thought that I saw another example recently in this group but I cannot find it now.

Today, I saw a reference to a 6th power in a comment to a question in Astronomy.
[Do planets lose energy while rotating?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50266/do-planets-lose-energy-while-rotating)

"Be aware that time to tidal lock scales, to a first approximation, with the sixth (6th) power of the orbital radius (SMA)."

Any examples of even higher powers?  Any more examples of fourth powers and higher?

Comment: Explanation of the downvote?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39151).

Comment: This is basically a big list question, without an identifiable 'correct' answer.

Comment: @J.G. I had not spotted that.  Indeed it is related but I would not say that it is the same.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks.  It is good to know why.  I'll consider deleting it.

Comment: @badjohn - I wasn't the downvoter, so that was just a guess...

Comment: Technically every formula that involves an analytical function contains a potentially infinite amount of terms that are raised to increasingly higher powers. In that sense, it is actually very common for physical quantities to depend on very high powers of other quantities.

Comment: @JonCuster But it was a valid point.

Comment: @rhomaios I considered mentioning and excluding that.  Maybe exclude powers of dimensionless quantities.

Comment: I upvoted because I think the topic itself is ambiguous and hard to define so it is very hard to seem focused on specific fields of physics

Answer (score 4):

Another famous fourth power is found in Rayleigh scattering, where the cross section goes up with the frequency to the fourth: $\nu^4$

For sixth and higher powers you got the famous Lennard-Jones molecular potential

$$V_\text{LJ}(r) = 4\varepsilon \left[ \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^6 \right]$$

Usually in molecular potentials you can find high power of the distance because of multipolar expansions.

I cannot think of higher examples, but I think you can find more things like that $1/r^6$ in tidal locking by looking at the physics of precision physics using general relativity or quantum field theory, as any phenomena involving these theories should be vanishing in regular conditions (for not-so-small distances, masses and velocities).

Comment: In this context, $12$ is a big number.

Comment: Notably, there's [no theoretical justification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential#Physical_background_and_mathematical_details) for the use of 12, unlike the use of 6. It's just easy to calculate as the square of the other term. But this nuance just illustrates why the original question is unanswerable: where do we draw the line between reality and model?

Answer (score 3):

In higher dimensions you get arbitrarily high powers, because of the geometry. For example, Coulomb's law in dimension $d$ scales as

$$\vec{F} =\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r^{d-1}}\hat{r}$$

An example of arbitrarily high powers without more spacial dimensions is the field of an electric multipole:

- A monopole is created by the electric field of a single particle, and scales as $\propto \frac{1}{r^2}$
- An electric dipole has two opposing charges, and its electric field scales as $\propto \frac{1}{r^3}$
- An electric quadropole consists of two positive and two negative charges,  its field scales as $\frac{1}{r^4}$

In general the electric field drops as $log_2(n) + 2$, where $n$ is the number of particles in the multipole. Out of curiosity, if you take $n$ to be of order Avogadro's number $n=10^{23}$, you get

$$|\vec{E}| \propto \frac{1}{r^{78}}$$

...which is not all that bad for so many particles!

Comment: Yes but I was hoping for something more real. Maybe I should add "high compared to the spatial dimension".  So, Stefan-Boltzmann qualifies in 3D space since it has a 4th power.

Comment: I understand, higher dimensions may not exist anyways. There is another example of arbitrarily high power in our own 3D.

Comment: I decided to delegate the volume flow rate example to the comments. As the radius of a pipe increases, the rate at which water flows through increases as $R^4$. Specifically,$$\text{Flow rate} = \frac{\pi r^4 (P_1 - P_2)}{ 8 \eta L}$$

$P_1 - P_2$ gives the pressure difference at opposite ends of the pipe. $L$ is length of the pipe and $\eta$ is the fluid viscosity. Flow rate is measured in volume per unit time.

Comment: You also have some big powers in GR. Check out this formula for the power emitted by gravitational waves of a two-planet system, scaling as $R^{-5}$: https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/g/gravitational+waves#:~:text=Gravitational%20radiation%20power,is%20only%20a%20few%20kilowatts!

Answer (score 0):

The [Toda potential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda_lattice) is exponential in the coordinates so contains all powers of the coordinates.

Comment: There are many exponentials in physics to be counted...